# how to escape [ ] in jsonPath

Tags: spring-test, jsonpath

How can I escape square brackets in a JSONPath matcher?

`.andExpect(jsonPath("$.fieldErrors.addresses[0].contactAddress1", Matchers.any(String.class)))`

doesn't match, even though the JSON exists, and I think it's because of the square brackets.

`"{\"errors\":[],\"fieldErrors\":{\"adminName\":\"Admin Name is a required field\",\"addresses[0].contactCompany\":\"Company is a required field\",\"addresses[0].contactAddress1\":\"Address is a required field\",\"addresses[0].contactPhoneNumber\":\"Phone Number cannot exceed 25 characters\"},\"uiMessageClass\":null,\"uiMessage\":null,\"redirectUrl\":null,\"object\":null}"`

Is there a way to escape the brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fieldErrors` does not contain a property named `addresses` that is an array or list. Thus you are using the wrong syntax.

Have you tried simply quoting the name of the property like this?

```java
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.fieldErrors['addresses[0].contactAddress1']", Matchers.any(String.class)))
```

For further details, consult the official [JsonPath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) documentation.

I also tried out your additional failing test that you discuss in the comments, but I cannot reproduce the problem. For example, the following test passes fine for me:

```java
@Test
public void test() {
    String input = "{\"errors\":[],\"fieldErrors\":{\"labels[en]\":\"Label is a required field\",\"externalIdentifier\":\"Identifier is a required field\"},\"uiMessageClass\":null,\"uiMessage\":null,\"redire‌​ctUrl\":null,\"objec‌​t\":null}";
    JsonPathExpectationsHelper jsonPath = new JsonPathExpectationsHelper("$.fieldErrors['labels[en]']");
    jsonPath.exists(input);
    jsonPath.assertValue(input, Matchers.any(String.class));
    jsonPath.assertValue(input, "Label is a required field");
}
```

Regards,

Sam

Comment: Hi Sam I just tried this on another test method with similar properties. But I got this error: `java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.fieldErrors['labels[en]']"
Expected: an instance of java.lang.String
     but: <{}> is a java.util.LinkedHashMap
 at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
 at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.assertValue`

Comment: this was the output JSON: `testUpdateShippingMethod_CreateNew_InvalidInput - "{\"errors\":[],\"fieldErrors\":{\"labels[en]\":\"Label is a required field\",\"externalIdentifier\":\"Identifier is a required field\"},\"uiMessageClass\":null,\"uiMessage\":null,\"redirectUrl\":null,\"object\":null}"
13:02:13.426 TRACE com.ocscommerce.admin.tests.unit.controllers.deliveries.ShippingMethodAjaxControllerUnitTest 305 testUpdateShippingMethod_CreateNew_InvalidInput - exit`

Comment: and the matcher: `                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.fieldErrors['labels[en]']", Matchers.any(String.class)))
`

Comment: What version of `spring-test` are you using?

Comment: FYI: I updated my answer to include a test showing that your above use case should work fine.